# How do i make an if statement with lists work

Tags: python

My Code:

```
team = ['barca', 'madrid']
fav_team = raw_input('What is your favorite team: ')
fav_team = fav_team.upper()
if fav_team in team:
    print "AWESOME"
```

Hello. I'm very new to programming, i have zero experience and I'm trying to make this work. But when i run this code, its not printing anything. I want to be able to make the user input his favorite team, and something prints out. But nothing comes out. how do i get the print statement to show?. I already tried using the input function and that did not work.

Comment: I'm no python expert, but you are comparing `.upper()` input with lowercase array.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call lower function.

```
team = ['barca', 'madrid']
fav_team = raw_input('What is your favorite team: ')
fav_team = fav_team.lower()
if fav_team in team:
    print "AWESOME"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
team = ['barca', 'madrid']
fav_team = raw_input('What is your favorite team: ')
fav_team = fav_team.lower()  #make upper lower
if fav_team in team:
    print "AWESOME"
```

You need to make your `upper` `lower` as *list contains elements in lower*.

This will still have errors if list has *capitals*. So make both lowercase.

```
if fav_team in map(str.lower,team):
    print "AWESOME"
```